# django-tenants global device table mapping to tenants

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-tenants

We are using django-tenants to provide a multi tenant solution for an iot platform and I'm having an issue figuring out how to map some global data to tenant specific tables. Basically we have iot devices that talk to a node.js server using a proprietary protocol over tcp, that server then makes rest api requests to a Django webserver to update the database with device measurements. The node server does not know anything about which device belongs to which customer so it needs to have a rest api that is global and then the webserver backend will need to map that device to a specific tenant but we cannot let tenants view each other's data so I'm not sure how we accomplish this as it seems apis are either tenant specific or global (public).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can structure the Django app in this way:

- Create a Tenant model
- Create a Measurement model
- Inside the Measurement model put a ForeingKey to Tenant
- Now you have to create endpoint that receive call from node.js server, and obviously inside the data you need to put the tenant information (such as uuid).

Use django-rest-framework for endpoint and protect it with authentication!